# Was sind „Naschis“ im Plattdeutschen?

Tags: dialect, low-german

Ich habe leider als Kind weder Platt gesprochen noch gehört, aber seit einiger Zeit höre ich die Podcasts des NDR, um wenigstens ein bisschen zu lernen. Ich verstehe das meiste. Aber mit [diesem Podcast](https://www.ndr.de/wellenord/Allns-foer-de-Tuenn,audio351046.html) habe ich Schwierigkeiten: so ab 1:17 kommen „Naschis“ vor.

Ich vermute es soll „Lekereien“ heißen, aber diese sind normalerweise „Leckereen“.

[Hier](http://www.platt-wb.de/hoch-platt/?term=S%C3%BC%C3%9Figkeit) finden Sie Synonyme. „Naschis“ ist nicht dabei und auch nicht im Wörterbuch verzeichnet. Auch [hier](http://www.plattdeutsches-woerterbuch.de/pages/plattdeutsches_woerterbuch.html) ist das Wort nicht verzeichnet.

Comment: Sollen das nicht einfach diese neumodischen runden Birnen aus Japan sein? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashi-Birne Kleine Süßigkeiten heißen in Norddeutschland **Bollchen** oder kurz **Bollos**.

Comment: @Janka glaube ich nicht, weil die nicht im gelben Sack landen. Aber vielen Dank.

Comment: Aber die Verpackungen, diese weißen Netze, in die sie ob ihres hohen Preises einzeln verpackt werden, landen im gelben Sack.

Comment: @Janka Aha. Könnte sein!

Comment: @Janka Glaube auch, dass das die Birnen sind & Du aus dem Kommentar eine Antwort machen kannst :)

Comment: Naschis (Naschies?) ist hier in Norddeutschland, zumindest für den Raum Kiel/Hamburg kann ich sprechen, ein ganz normaler und selbstverständlicher Begriff für Süßigkeiten. Vor allem verwendet von Kindern oder wenn es ein bisschen niedlich klingen soll und auch vor allem für "Naschi-Tüten", damit verbinde ich vor allem kleine weiße Papiertüten mit einzeln ausgesuchten und zusammengestellten Süßigkeiten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich kenne Naschi oder Naschis für Süßigkeiten. Das passt auch gut in den Zusammenhang, da es ja um die ungesunde Ernährung der Nachbarn geht. Die Naschi-Tüten sind dann die Plastik-Umverpackungen. 
Das scheint ein norddeutscher Begriff zu sein, der zum Beispiel auch in [dieser](https://www.ffn.de/on-air/programm/norddeutsche-begriffe/) Auflistung vorkommt. Wie stark und in welchen Regionen er im Plattdeutschen vertreten ist, kann ich nicht sagen.

Answer (score 0):

Da das in Zusammenhang mit Bio steht, können mit *Naschis* nur diese Birnen gemeint sein. Deren Verpackung erzeugt Plastemüll, da die alle oft einzeln in Netze verpackt sind. Also, es ist kein plattdeutsches Wort - kann's auch schlecht geben, da es diese Früchte früher gar nicht gab.